# Calling static method without a reference variable

Tags: java, variables, methods, reference, static

Why don't you need a reference variable in ***"method1( );"*** in order to call a static method from main?

```
public class MainClass { 
  public static void method1() { 
    System.out.println("Method1"); 
  }
  public static void main(String[ ] args) { 
    method1(); 
  } 
}
```

Without instantiating an Object variable like this for non static methods:

```
MainClass var = new MainClass();
var.method1();
```

Comment: They're both static methods, within the same declarative scope, I mean, you did point out *Whereas in a **non static method** you make the call like this*

Comment: Does that have to do with the space in memory allocated to static events?

Comment: Static methods are loaded with the class definition, and not bound to an instance of the class

Comment: Is this a philosophical discourse? That's how scopes work and is merely a mechanism of the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static members ( Method, Field) does NOT belong to any object instances. Static members exists Even there is NO object instance created. Static members SHARED for all object instances. That is why when you access static members, you DON'T have to use any object instances.

For your case:

```
var1.method1() = var2.method1() = var3.method1() = MainClass.method1()
```

Because they are calling the same static member instance. BUT you are recommended that static members should be accessed in static way.

Answer (score 0):

`static members` are `class member` not specific to object so we don't need of object. the best example is `public static void main(String [] args)` method itself.